# Keep the color of menu item static on click

Tags: css, html

Ok so I have the follow menu:

```
<div class="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="/index.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about.aspx">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Associated with this CSS class:

```
.header {
    margin:20px 0 55px;
    height:68px;
    width:inherit;
}
```

What can I put in my menu tag or my CSS class to make the link **not change colors** when it is clicked. Currently the link will be blue but once it has been clicked it turns purple. I want it to be say black all the time, clicked or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No better way than to quote the specs:

```
a:link    { color: red }    /* unvisited links */
a:visited { color: blue }   /* visited links   */
a:hover   { color: yellow } /* user hovers     */
a:active  { color: lime }   /* active links    */
a:active  { color: gray }   /* when element accepts tab focus */
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes

So this should cover all cases:

```
.header a,
.header a:link,
.header a:visited,
.header a:active,
.header a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZgUZn/1/

Joerg noted in a comment below the question that I omitted `:focus`. I did, and for a reason, but I'll note why and you can consider if you need it or not:

```
.header a:focus {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZgUZn/5/

Go to that link, click in the white part of the page in the bottom, right quarter, then hit the `TAB` key. You'll see that when that element receives focus, it changes. You can cover that by including this psuedo-class, but it's my understanding that browsers do not have a default setting for this, so unless you set it somewhere else and you need to cancel it out, it *might* be unnecessary.

**NOTE:** I seem to remember in the back of my mind recently I found out that just [`.header a` may also work](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgUZn/2/), but honestly I'm not sure how, and I've always understood the above is how it should be done (belt-and-suspenders notwithstanding). Comments welcome on this point.

**EDIT**

As to the above note, I think I've got an answer:

```
a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    background: green;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.header a {
    color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZgUZn/6/

The `.header a` does not override all of the psuedo-selectors if they have been declared elsewhere. Now, if there aren't any others declared, it [appears to work](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgUZn/7/) in overriding the browser's defaults, but that may be a false-positive.

Comment: you forgot: a:focus {color: grey;}

Comment: Note that active must always come after hover: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html

Comment: Very nice quick answer. Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @Joerg - I made a note about why it was left out initially. You brought up a good point, so I think it's best to also discuss `:focus`.

Comment: @Emerica - I added some information about `:focus`, which you may be interested in reading.

Comment: @AramKocharyan really? never heard of that before... and i'm not sure that this is true... because you can define them solo, as jared did at the beginning of the text - i'm sure that with a normal browser (incl. also old IE6) it doesn't matter at all!

Comment: @Joerg according to the article I cited it does, and I've come across the problem twice myself

Comment: @AramKocharyan http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes - allright, an Information i never read before - and hopefully did every time right ;)  thx for the info...

Answer (score 1):

That's the default colors assigned by the browser for visited and unvisited links. If you don't want it to change then just style the anchor tags.

```
.header a {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: As I noted in my answer, I was thinking this might be the answer, but only if there is not another selector which might provide those psuedo-selectors. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgUZn/6/